# Create/transform polynomial so that all critical points are in the [0, 1] range

Tags: polynomials

I want to get a real power $n$ polynomial with the property that all critical points are in the [0, 1] range.
I see two strategies here: 
1) Get any power-$n$ polynomial; learn the [real part of] the critical points, find min and max $x$ of the critical points and do linear scaling of the polynomial to bring the critical point to the desired range.
2) Construct the polynomial in some way that ensures the critical points are in the required range.

A failed idea was to define the polynomial by its roots: $r_i$, $i = 1..n$, $r_i > r_{i-1}$, $r_0=0$, $\sum r_i = 1$ and $p(x) = \prod (x-r_i)$.
The problem with that approach is that it constrains the polynomial to have exactly $n$ roots which I do not want.

I could try to define the polynomial by its complex roots, but it seems to me that constraining the polynomial to be real would be to messy for the intended application (neural networks).

I just got the idea that for even $n$ I could probably define the polynomial in the following way: $p(x)=\prod{(x^2 + k_ix+b_i)}$. Does this form constrain the set of possible polynomials in some way? How can I constrain the critical points for a polynomial in this form?

P.S. The context requires that the polynomial is differentiable by the real parameters used to derive the coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see myself two possibilities; one which seems a little bit rave/rock and one which is more elegant.

For the first one, let $p(x)=p_0+p_1x+p_2x^2+\dots+p_nx^n$ with $p_n\neq0$. Since $p$ is a polynomial, it is differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$, so every critical point of $p$ will be a root of $p'$ and inversely. Since $p$ is of $\deg(p)=n$, it is evident that $\deg(p')=n-1$, so $p'$ has at most $n-1$ roots; let $r_1,r_2,\dots,r_{n-1}$ be these roots. Note that, should $p'$ have no roots, then there are no critical points for $p$, so the requested holds in a trivial way. Also note that, should all these roots be $0$, again the requested holds.

Let
$$R=\max\{|r_i|:i=1,2,\dots,n-1\}$$
Then, we set
$$q(x)=p\left(2Rx+R\right)$$
and we get that - by the cahin rule:
$$q'(x)=2Rp'\left(2Rx+R\right)$$
Note now that $q$ is of $\deg(q)=n$ and for every $i=1,2,\dots,n-1$, we have:
$$q'\left(\frac{r_i+R}{2R}\right)=2Rp'\left(2\left(\frac{r_i+R}{2R}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\right)=2Rp'(r_i)=0$$
So, the roots of $q'$ are exactly the numbers $$t_i=\frac{r_i+R}{2R},\ i=1,2,\dots,n-1$$
Note now that, for every $i=1,2,\dots,n-1$:
$$-R\leq r_i\leq R\Rightarrow0\leq r_i+R\leq2R\Rightarrow0\leq t_i\leq1$$

Finally, all of $q$'s critical points are in $[0,1]$.

So we have a way to "transform" ecery polynomial $p$ to another polynomial $q$ with the requested property.

For the second one, we can use Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind, which are defined as:
$$T_n(x)=\cos(n\arccos x),\ |x|\leq1$$
for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

First note that $T_n$ is trully a polynomial, sincce, by substituting $\arccos x$ with $u$, we note that:
$$T_n(x)=\cos(nu)$$
and, from known trigonometric identities, we know that $\cos(nu)$ is a polyonimix expresion of $\cos u$. Since $\cos u=\cos(\arccos x)=x$, we have that $T_n$ is a polynomial with respect to $x$.

Moreover, it is quite interesting that these polynomials have all their roots - which are exactly $n$ - as well as their critical points in $[-1,1]$ and, hence, with a transformation similar to the previous one, we can transport them to $[0,1]$.

Hope this helped! :)